# Easiest way to find a refrigerant leak on a 1999 Olds Intrigue

Tags: ac, leak, oldsmobile

I had the level of the refrigerant checked and it was low, and the guy i bought the car from said he hadn't driven it in over a year, so I bought a can and filled it up. Air cooled off a bit then warmed up again. checked the level again and it was low again. I'm assuming this is a pretty bad leak. What's the easiest way to find the leak and/or fix this issue. It doesn't seem like refrigerant with the stop leak stuff with help this one bit, plus i heard they're not a very good option anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you consider easy. It's possible to fill your system and then spray the entire ac system down with soapy water to watch for air bubbles escaping from the lines, but this is a tedious task. There are cans of refrigerant with uv dye placed in them also, so what you can do is fill your system with one of the uv dye cans and then drive around for a few days with your ac on. Then, you either find a uv light for yourself to look for the leak or take it into a mechanic in order for them to look for the leaked dye. AC systems are typically troublesome and require a good deal of effort to diagnose problems unfortunately. Good luck with your leak hunting.

Comment: don't forget you can use a leak detector/sniffer. they're generally pretty cheap and work a lot faster than spraying the system with water.

Comment: +1 also very good suggestion. I'd completely forgotten about those (long time since messing with ac system)